# Gatsby - IntersectionObserver is not defined

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, polyfills, intersection-observer

I am trying to build my gatsby project but I am unable due to the IntersectionObserver not being recognized. I use the intersectionObserver inside an InView component:

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react'


const InView = ({ children }) => {
    const [boundingClientY, setBoundingClientY] = useState(null)
    const [direction, setDirection] = useState(null)
    const [element, setElement] = useState(null)
    const [inView, setInView] = useState(false)



    const observer = useRef(new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
        const first = entries[0]
        const { boundingClientRect } = first
        first.isIntersecting && setInView(true)
        !first.isIntersecting && setInView(false)
        boundingClientRect.y > boundingClientY && setDirection('down')
        boundingClientRect.y < boundingClientY && setDirection('up')
        boundingClientY && setBoundingClientY(first.boundingClientRect.y)

    }))


    useEffect(() => {
        const currentElement = element
        const currentObserver = observer.current
        currentElement && currentObserver.observe(currentElement)
        // console.log(currentObserver)
        return () => {
            currentElement && currentObserver.unobserve(currentElement)
        };
    }, [element])

    const styles = {
        opacity: inView ? 1 : 0,
        transform: `
            translateY(${!inView ?
                direction === 'up' ? '-20px' : '20px'
                : 0})
            rotateY(${!inView ? '35deg' : 0})
            scale(${inView ? 1 : 0.9})
            `,
        transition: 'all 0.4s ease-out 0.2s'
    }

    return (
        <div ref={setElement} style={styles}>

            {children}

        </div>
    )
}

export default InView
```

I have a wrapper for the root element to enable a global state and have tried importing the polyfill inside gatsby-browser.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import GlobalContextProvider from './src/components/context/globalContextProvider'

export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
    return (
        <GlobalContextProvider>
            {element}
        </GlobalContextProvider>
    )
}

export const onClientEntry = async () => {
    if (typeof IntersectionObserver === `undefined`) {
        await import(`intersection-observer`);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is an error on build, right ($ gatsby build)? If that's the case this has nothing to do with browser support.

It is the fact that `IntersectionObserver` is a browser API and you should not use browser APIs during server side rendering. Instead you try to utilize them after components have mounted. To solve this initialize your observer in `useEffect()` instead of `useRef()` as you currently do.

```
...
const observer = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  observer.current = new IntersectionObserver({ ... });
}, []); // do this only once, on mount
...
```

Answer (score 1):

IntersectionObserver API is a browser API and it can't be executed during Gatbsy build process. Therefore, you should check if your code is running in browser:

```
let observer = null;
if (typeof window !== "undefined"){ // The code inside brackets will be executed ONLY in browser
    observer = new IntersectionObserver(/* ... */);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got my jest test to pass by placing this before the creation of "new IntersectionObserver"

```js
if (!window.IntersectionObserver) return
```

Answer (score 0):

declare a let variable = null. this also works in NextJS

```
...
let observer = null

useEffect(()=> {
observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback,optional);
},[])
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to all the previous answers above, I have my trick that at least works for Next.js Static Export. So the trick is instead of directly using the `IntersectionObserver` constructor to create the object we can create custom factory that returns a mock in non browser environment. Here's my sample code:

```js
// intersectionObserverFactory.ts
const isBrowser = () =>
  Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(globalThis)) !== Object.prototype;
const createIntersectionObserver = (callback, options) => {
  if (isBrowser()) {
    return new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
  }
  return {
    observe: () => {
      /* do nothing */
    },
  };
};

export default createIntersectionObserver;
```

And in another part of the code:

```js
import createIntersectionObserver from '@/helpers/intersectionObserverFactory';

useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const observer = createIntersectionObserver(
        (entries) => {
          entries.forEach((entry) => {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
              entry.target.classList.add('animate');
            } else {
              entry.target.classList.remove('animate');
            }
          });
        },
        {
          threshold: 0.75,
        }
      );
      refItemRoadmap.current
        .querySelectorAll('.progress-bar')
        .forEach((snap) => {
          observer.observe(snap);
        });
    }
  }, []);
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just removed `node_module` folder and `package-lock.json`, then `npm i` and it worked !