# How to use IntersectionObserver with React hooks in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby

### [Example on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-react-hooks-intersectionobserver-s51yt?file=/src/pages/index.js)

---

I am creating a website using Gatsby and am having trouble converting a class component, which uses `IntersectionObserver`, into a functional component that uses hooks. I am particularly looking for a solution that minimizes the amount of re-renders as possible.

My class component is shown below:

**Parent component using `React.Component`**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import ChildComponent from "../components/child"

class ParentComponent extends Component {
  observer = null

  componentDidMount() {
    this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(this.handleObserverEvent, {})
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.observer.disconnect()
    this.observer = null
  }

  handleObserverEvent = entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => console.log(entry))
  }

  observeElement = ref => {
    if (this.observer) this.observer.observe(ref)
  }

  render() {
    const colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue"]

    return (
      <div>
        {colors.map(color => (
          <ChildComponent
            key={color}
            color={color}
            observeElement={this.observeElement}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ParentComponent
```

**Child component**

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react"

const ChildComponent = ({ color, observeElement }) => {
  const ref = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) observeElement(ref.current)
  }, [observeElement])

  return (
    <div
      className={color}
      ref={ref}
      style={{
        width: "100vw",
        height: "100vh",
        background: color
      }}
    >
      {color}
    </div>
  )
}

export default ChildComponent
```

This current setup works well. I am able to observe `ParentComponent`'s children using `IntersectionObserver`.

However, I need to convert this component into a functional component. I tried to implement this same logic using `useRef`, but cannot achieve the same result. In `observeElement`, `observer.current` is equal to `null`. My functional component is shown below.

**Parent component using `useRef`**

```js
// Omitted imports/exports

const handleObserverEvent = entries => {
  entries.forEach(entry => console.log(entry))
}

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const observer = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    observer.current = new IntersectionObserver(handleObserverEvent, {})

    return () => {
      if (observer.current) observer.current.disconnect()
      observer.current = null
    }
  }, [])

  const observeElement = ref => {
    console.log(observer.current) // Logs null
    if (observer.current) observer.current.observe(ref)
  }

  const colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue"]

  return (
    <div>
      {colors.map(color => (
        <ChildComponent
          key={color}
          color={color}
          observeElement={observeElement}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

To combat this, I opted to use `useState` to trigger a re-render, which works. However, I am wondering if the same thing can be achieved using `useRef` and possibly some other hooks.

**Parent component using `useState`**

```js
// Omitted imports/exports

const handleObserverEvent = entries => {
  // This successfully logs the entries
  entries.forEach(entry => console.log(entry))
}

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [observer, setObserver] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    setObserver(new IntersectionObserver(handleObserverEvent, {}))

    return () => {
      if (observer) observer.disconnect()
    }
  }, [])

  const observeElement = ref => {
    if (observer) observer.observe(ref)
  }

  const colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue"]

  return (
    <div>
      {colors.map(color => (
        <ChildComponent
          key={color}
          color={color}
          observeElement={observeElement}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

---

#### Notes

1. I can't set `new IntersectionObserver()` as the initial value in `useRef`. This is because it throws an error when running `gatsby build`. According to this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59426367/11715889), `IntersectionObserver` is unavailable during Gatsby's build process since Gatsby uses server-side rendering.

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const observer = useRef(new IntersectionObserver())
  // Throws an error: IntersectionObserver is not defined.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your problem with useRef is pretty simple. You are triggering `observeElement` function from child's `useEffect`. and `useEffect` in child runs before the useEffect in parent so `observeElement` runs before the observer is actually initialised.

Now if you would have not been using Gatsby the solution would be to initialize observer within useRef itself.

However the best solution in the above case is to actually store the observer in state and trigger a re-render so that the `observeElement` function is called again from the child and it actually will now have the observer to work which is what you have already suggested in your post

Other solutions involve moving the ref of all children into the parent and triggering the observer from parent itself on each child but its quite hacky.